# angular2 / RxJS - how to retry from inside subscribe()

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular2-observables

this is my code:

```
this._api.getCompanies().subscribe(
    res => this.companies = JSON.parse(res),
    exception => {if(this._api.responseErrorProcess(exception)) { // in case this retured TRUE then I need to retry() } }
)
```

in case an exception happened, it will be sent to a function in the API then return `true` if the problem is fixed (like token refreshed for example) and it just needs to retry again after its fixed

I could not figure out how to make it retry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `.getCompanies()` call right after the `.map` add a [`.retryWhen`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/retrywhen.md):

```ts
.retryWhen((errors) => {
    return errors.scan((errorCount, err) => errorCount + 1, 0)
                 .takeWhile((errorCount) => errorCount < 2);
});
```

In this example, the observable completes after 2 failures (`errorCount < 2`).

Comment: I'm not sure about how `errors` looks like. I think it's an array of exceptions (maybe?). So you could extend the `takeWhile` condition to: `errorCount < 2 && this._api.responseErrorProcess(errors[0])`

Comment: this is what I was gonna ask, I'll check it up thank you a lot :)
actually this way I can centralize the error handling from the api directly, instead of adding the exception in each subsribtion, thank you.!

Comment: You could add a `console.log(errors)` before the `return` to see how it's structured.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
this._api.getCompanies().subscribe(this.updateCompanies.bind(this))

updateCompanies(companies, exception) {
    companies => this.companies = JSON.parse(companies),
    exception => {
        if(this._api.responseErrorProcess(exception)) {
            // in case this retured TRUE then I need to retry()
            this.updateCompanies(companies, exception)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: well I thought there's a way to retry() the observable natively from rxjs, but this would work too thanks .

Comment: Be aware, that this example can possibly deadlock.

Comment: After a closer look, this also doesn't retry the actual call to the server, just calls the callback function :D